# MySQL - multiple MAX values with date

Tags: mysql, select, max

I have table structure:

**A | B | C | Date**

And I want to select MAX(A), MAX(B), MAX(C) and to every MAX assign Date ... can it be done in MySQL with only 1 SELECT (no temporal tables like SELECT * FROM (SELECT ....)) ?

Example:

```
A  | B  | C  | Date
------------------------
10 | 20 | 0  | 25.5.2012
0  | 13 | 7  | 25.3.2012
70 | 5  | 15 | 25.4.2012

Result:
A -> 70 - 25.4.2012
B -> 20 - 25.5.2012
C -> 15 - 25.4.2012
```

Comment: can you give sample records with desired result?

Comment: explain your problem clearly with table structure and what you need in output

Comment: `and to every MAX assign Date` is too confusing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  ( SELECT 'A' AS ColumnM
          , a  AS Result
          , Date
    FROM tableX  
    ORDER BY a DESC
        LIMIT 1 
  )
UNION ALL
  ( SELECT 'B'
          , b 
          , Date
    FROM tableX  
    ORDER BY b DESC
        LIMIT 1 
  )
UNION ALL
  ( SELECT 'C'
          , c 
          , Date
    FROM tableX  
    ORDER BY c DESC
        LIMIT 1 
  ) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need this ::

```
Select
MAX(a),
MAX(b),
MAX(c)
from table
GROUP BY `Date`
```